# How to deflate a differential operator

Tags: sobolev-spaces, quotient-spaces, differential-operators

Since I don't have a proper academic training in functional analysis, please forgive any error below or abuse of notation.

Let $\Omega=(0,1)$ be the unit open interval. 
Let $H^k(\Omega) = W^{k,2}(\Omega, \mathbb R)$ denote the Sobolev space of order $k$. 
Let $D: H^k(\Omega) \to H^{k-1}(\Omega)$, $k>0$ be the differential operator defined by $D u = u', \forall u \in H^k(\Omega)$.
Finally let $B_\alpha : H^2(\Omega) \to L_2(\Omega)$, $\alpha \in \bar \Omega$ be defined by $B_\alpha u = u'(\alpha)$.

I would like to construct a deflated complimentary operator $\bar D: H^2(\Omega) \to L_2(\Omega)$ such that $\text{im}(\bar D) = \text{im}(D) / \text{im}(B_\alpha)$ so that $\text{im}(D) = \text{im}(\bar D) \oplus \text{im}(B_\alpha)$.

How can I build such an operator? and make its definition explicit?

Comment: Is $B_\alpha u$ a constant function? If both $\text{im}(D)$ and $\text{im}(B_\alpha)$ are subspaces of $L^2(\Omega)$ (I guess $k=1$), how do you define their quotient so that it's also a subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$? Or should I just look at the second condition $\text{im}(D) = \text{im}(\bar D) \oplus \text{im}(B_\alpha)$?

Comment: yes, $B_\alpha$ maps any function $u \in H^k$ to constant functions  $u'(\alpha) \in L_2$, so $\text{rank}(\text{im}(B_\alpha))=1$ and for this example $k=1$ is enough. A typical application would be to use multiple operator $B_\alpha$ to exactly match the derivative at specific locations, and then work in the complimentary subspace with the deflated operator $\bar D$ to improve the approximation in a least-square sense.